# Adding multiple values to arraylist from user input

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I just have a quick question about adding to an array list. I have an arraylist which shows some details about different books (Name, Genre, Author and Year Published). How can I make it so that a user can input all these values (name, genre, etc) into multiple textboxes and then click a button to add all the details as a new book in the list?

Below is my code so far:

```
namespace LibraryBooks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Object> library = new List<Object>();
        int current = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeArrayList();
            DisplayData();
        }
        public void DisplayData()
        {
            Books b = (Books)library[current];
            textBox1.Text = "" + b.readTitle();
            textBox2.Text = "" + b.readGenre();
            textBox3.Text = "" + b.readAuthor();
            textBox4.Text = "" + b.readYearPublished();
        }
        public void InitializeArrayList()
        {
            library.Add(new Books("The Hunger Games", "Adventure", "Suzanne Collins", "2008"));
            library.Add(new Books("Gone Girl", "Thriller", "Gillian Flynn", "2014"));
            library.Add(new Books("A Game of Thrones", "Fantasy", "George R.R. Martin", "1996"));
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (movies.Contains(textBox7.Text))
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
    public class Test92
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about it at all so any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is `library` a `List<Object>` and not a `List<Books>` (or rather, `List<Book>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Create all the textboxes you need for each input, and then in your button_click method, write something along the lines of

```
library.Add(new Books(textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text));
```

This functions very similarly to what your InitializeArrayList method does, but instead of passing pre-determined text to your Books constructor, it takes in text from the textboxes on your form.

Comment: I would suggest using a masktextbox for the year variable. The books class looks like it can be book in singular. As a coding convention, plural of things is reserved for collections. I suggest renaming the class to book.